# In Excel is it possible to specify exact spacing for EDI in each cell so it will align when printed to text

Tags: excel, export-to-excel, edi

In Excel is it possible to specify exact spacing for EDI in each cell so it will align when printed to text in an EDI line?  The reason I wanted to know is because the start of a cell has a line on it and it may be good to break up an EDI file.  My goal is to export to a text file and then have my edi file perfectly line up.  Is this possible in excel?  thx

[Similiar Stack overflow but not related to EDI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967199/how-to-get-the-exact-text-a-user-entered-into-a-cell-in-excel)

Comment: Not sure I follow... are you comparing 2 EDI files of the same format?

Comment: No, I want the first cell to have exactly 5 characters, second cell to have 2 char, etc...  Then when it exports to an edi file it looks like this:  "abcd_c2".

Comment: By default none of the export options get you where you need to get. to complicate matters further, rolling your own export function using vba will be problematic as there is a limit of 256 characters when moving strings from vba to excel. My advice would be to export as tab delimited then feed the file into a program in another language (whichever you know best) to create the text file.

Answer (score 1):

As I stated in the comments I don't think there is a default excel option to achieve this.

I have thought of a somewhat clumsy way using formulas to get there using formulas and a couple of tabs

sheet 1 - your original data (named 'Original Input' in the formula below.)

sheet 2 - each column would be mirrored to your original data but instead of column headings, row 1 would contain the number of characters. Use the following formula for each cell

```
=CONCATENATE('Original input'!A2,REPT("_",'Sheet adding underscores'!A$1-LEN('Original input'!A2)))
```

In summary that formula  inserts one "_" for the difference between the length defined for the field and the length of the string in the original data cell.

in your example above in would convert `abcd` into `abcd_`

sheet 3 - use a (possibly tedious) concatenate formula to glue all of your cells from tab 2 together

```
=CONCATENATE('Sheet adding underscores'!A2,'Sheet adding underscores'!B2,...etc)
```

With sheet 3 highlighted you can now export a text file of any format and your edifile should match up exactly.